# make image width responsive with ink email framework

Tags: html, css, email, zurb-ink

I'm using [Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) for a responsive Email layout and would like to ask, how I can make an image responsive, like it fills out the container responsively. I tried `<img width="100%">` on the image tag (since CSS' width wouldn't be supportet by some clients) but it didn't work.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that no additional tags or width specifications are needed on the images. I tested the Emails on [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) and the pictures are completely responsive. They aren't in the browser, which is why I thought there is a width needed, but it isn't! This framework is really awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img style="width:100%;">`

Comment: as I mentioned, this won't work for Outlook, because Outlook does not allow `width` on specific HTML tags.